# After successful login the screen is stuck on dark red and never shows desktop - Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: login, gui, settings, 18.04

I installed Ubuntu 18.04,
then continued with installing the software I need,
then continued with changing some settings, then the screen froze, I had to shut the computer off with the power button.
After that the computer booted fine until the login screen, whereafter a successful login a dark red screen is shown, the mouse cursor is shown and I can move it, but nothing else happens. The desktop is not shown.

The setting that I changed when it froze had something to do with indicator applets if I remember correctly, I just switched it from off to on and then the computer froze.

I have no idea how to debug or fix this. Any ideas, please?

**Update**
The settings I changed were to show the day of week in the clock, and set lock screen to 3 minutes, change background image to the standard ubuntu image showing a mountain range. After that I toggled the indicator applets  from off to on and then the computer froze instantly, it did not even update the toggle image of the switch to on before it froze. All settings were changed through the settings GUI.

Comment: You say "changed some settings, then the screen froze" - can you please elaborate on that?

Comment: @SDsolar I have added more details now. Thanks!

Comment: Upvote for that.  That sure sounds like a safe thing to do.  I hope this generates some useful answers for you.   Has it frozen like that again?  Like, perhaps, if you go back in and tweak another setting or two?

Comment: Can you try a few things and report back please? (1) Switch to a virtual console (Ctrl+Alt+F2) and log in there. (2) Create a new (test) user account (`sudo adduser mytestuser`) and try to log into the account with a graphical session.

Comment: @DavidFoerster That did it! I can log in with the new user ok. The old user still has the same old problem. Thank you so much! This makes the computer usable again.

Comment: Thanks! That confirms my suspicion. You can either reset the GNOME configuration of your original user account (and delete the test account) or migrate the old account’s data to the new account (and delete it). See the linked duplicate question.